# How to use/share data between steps?

Tags: python, cucumber

I have two different steps and pass in the same variable there.

Scenario1:

```
 Given the user lands on the page

 When user enters a unique email address
 Then user is redirected to checkout
 Then user places the order
```

Scenario2:

```
 Given the user lands on the same page
 When the user enters the same email address above
 Then user is presented with a modal window saying you already taken this offer
```

Is it possible to use the same generated unique email address to be used on the second scenario?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean. What does it mean to use the "same generated unique email address"? Is it possible to enter the same email address twice on the same page? Yes it is.

Comment: You have to find a way to persist the fact that checkout occurred. Traditional ways of doing this are cookies, sessions, and backend-databases. Which choice is right for you can not  be known with the limited criteria given.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't. You can use for any number of scenario's. As per scenario 1 steps, you already know the unique email address what you need to enter. Take this email address to the Hooks file and store it in one public static variable inside Before annotation. Later you can use same email for n number of scenario's using that public static variable.

If you need to use this email only for specific scenario's, add one tag to all scenario's which you need to use and tag it in Hooks file using Before({tags: tagName}). By this way, you can use this email address only for specific scenario's out of all.